# How to sort out situation where two questions ask about essentially the same thing, yet answers are opposite?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What Is The Difference, If Any, Between "Permanent", and "Until Dispelled"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68400/10642)

[Can a permanent teleportation circle be dispelled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136235/10642)

Answers to first one says it can't be dispelled, answers to second one says it can. Questions are close to being duplicates. If I'll try to ask which one is right, I'll essentially post a 3rd duplicate, and it is not useful to keep answers based on one set of sources in one place, and answers based on another set in another place.

So how would I go about looking for some kind of consensus? Or at least showing that there is no consensus, in a way visible to readers of both questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You vote to close as duplicate. When you do that, we can merge the questions from the duplicate to the other.  Then, normal site mechanisms will help determine who the community thinks is right.

Comment: OK, they are marked duplicates, and older one got answer that accounts for new data. Looks like it turns out pretty good. Thank you.

Comment: I have merged them.

Comment: Since the questions have already been merged, this comment is only as a clarification that both are not exact duplicate, and should not be merged. The older one is asking the difference between "until dispelled" and "permanent". Mine is asking whether "permanent teleportation circle" can be dispelled, mainly because it is no longer an active spell, only inscription/writing. If you take a look at the merged answers from my question, they are clearly out of place and do not seem to answer the old question at all.

Comment: @mxyzplk See this question: [Non-duplicate questions, with opposite correct answers, merged](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8599/non-duplicate-questions-with-opposite-correct-answers-merged)